# How do i upload photos from my mobile to computer(Web Site) using MMS and PHP?

Tags: php, mms, mms-gateway

Here the main thing is MMS a Pic to our wbsite, user can't access or browse the internet.
Just he need to send a MMS to is www.domain-name.com, i need to receive that and process in my website.

Questions:-

Is this possible or not?
   If Possible give some guidance.

Comment: You will need a gateway provider for this. Do you have a budget? What country are you in?

Comment: Most phones and carriers allow to send MMS to email addresses. So `mms@domain-name.com` should already do the trick.

Comment: I am from India, My father is having business, so need that service, i can invest money on that

Comment: @Mario — **from** the phone **to** the website

Comment: @David: Yes, you can send email-marshalled MMS **from** the phone. Any target email address (info@example.com) should work. Just requires a pop3/procmail handler.

Answer (score 3):

Peffisaur is a project that a guy has created that allows users to submit MMS's to his website and then it displays them on his website. Is this what you are looking to do?

http://hellkvist.org/software/#Peffisaur - Code

http://peffis.com/ - Implementation

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this for a business I would suggest getting a [Short Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_code) with an SMS/MMS Aggragator like [OpenMarket](http://www.openmarket.com/)

There is a chance (though I have never done this) you could create a email with the photo as an attachment and send to the [MMS email gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways) (if the carrier allows this).

Example:

- Alltel (US): number@mms.alltel.net (MMS)
- AT&T   (US): domestic-number@mms.att.net (MMS)

If you try the second option, please post back your results