# MMS Service or Email service for application

Tags: php, email, image-processing, mobile, mms

I need some help figuring out how to develop the following proposed solution:

Users should be able to send a photo via MMS message to a number - this image then needs to be picked up and processed through a web application. The application is currently written in PHP and works with manual file upload, how could I incorporate the MMS functionality into this so that it could process the users image. The application takes an image and modifies it. This is the final image that would need to be returned to the user (again via MMS)

Secondly, there also needs to be functionality for a user to email an image to an address (eg email@example.com) - the application then takes the image, processes it through the application and emails it back to the user.

Any advice or direction would be much appreicated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i upload photos from my mobile to computer(Web Site) using MMS and PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958231/how-do-i-upload-photos-from-my-mobile-to-computerweb-site-using-mms-and-php)

Answer (score 0):

For the SMS aspect of your requirements, you should check out [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/), they are for sending and receiving SMS, thought I'm not sure how they function with MMS. Still worth looking over though.